# Como puedo usar preg_match para filtrar una etiqueta html

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de poder obtener el resultado de un string.

este es mi string

```
$string = "<HTML><BODY><Form name='F1' action='https://miweb.to/' target='_parent' method='POST'><textarea name=\"op\">upload_result</textarea><textarea name=\"fn\">uau6cin6v0se</textarea><textarea name=\"st\">OK</textarea></Form><Script>document.location='javascript:false';document.F1.submit();</Script></BODY></HTML>";
```

quiero obtener lo que esta dento de las etiquetas `<textarea name=\"fn\">uau6cin6v0se</textarea>`
osea **uau6cin6v0se**

eh probado esto

```
preg_match_all("/name=\"fn\">([\w\d])</", $string, $matches);
```

pero no me funciona

de antemano gracias por cualquier ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero, como estás buscando un valor específico no necesitas utilizar la función `preg_match_all` si no que con `preg_match` te bastaría. En caso de que quisieras encontrar todas las ocurrencias dentro del string entonces si que deberías utilizar `preg_match_all`.

Después, podrías sustituir `([\w\d])` por `(.*?)` en tu regex de manera que tu función quedara así:

```
preg_match("/name=\"fn\">(.*?)</", $string, $matches);
```

Y tu valor lo encontrarías accediendo al valor `$matches[1]`.

[**Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/324a75f063abc9e79c39d836e63951c7765b1583)

Comment: EXELENTE! muchas gracias funciona perfectamente... de tanto probar también me funciono de esta manera `preg_match('/name="fn">([\w\-]+)</', $string, $matches);` hay alguna diferencia?

Comment: @juenDiegoGuzman Realmente no soy experto en regex pero creo que lo que estás haciendo en tu caso es obtener todas las letras y el guión (en caso de que lo tuviera). De hecho, si quitas el `\-` también funciona, solamente dejando `\w` pero te funciona en este caso ya que solamente tienes números y letras (la `\w` obtiene elementos alphanuméricos, es decir, letras y números más el guión bajo). En caso de que tuvieras algún carácter que no fuera alphanumérico (p.ej caracteres especiales) no te funcionaría. Por eso en mi ejemplo he puesto que acepte cualquier carácter que esté entre los dos tags.